# How to decode an image file path saved to SQLite database and display in ImageView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So here is what I am struggling with at the moment.  I am saving the image taken by the camera to my SQLite database by using this code:

DatabaseDB:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
            FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
            FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
            FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
            FIELD_ZOOM + " text , " +
            FIELD_IMG + " text " +
            " ) ";

    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Then in the camera intent (Main Activity)

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File cameraFolder;
            if   (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                cameraFolder = new    File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MapImages/");
            else
                cameraFolder= context.getFilesDir();
            if(!cameraFolder.exists())
                cameraFolder.mkdirs();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File photo = new File(cameraFolder, "MapImages/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");
            getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
            Uri.fromFile(photo);
            startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, TAKE_PICTURE);

            drawMarker(point);
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, point.latitude);
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, point.longitude);
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM, mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
            contentValues.put(FIELD_IMG, String.valueOf(photo));
            LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();
            insertTask.execute(contentValues);
```

So when I look in the database it save the image file location as:

```
/storage/emulated/0/MapImages/MapImages/JPEG_20211105_091000_.jpg
```

So that all works great! But how do I now go about retrieving that image and displaying it in a `ImageView`?

I have tried this (in the onloadFinished)

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    int locationCount = 0;
    double lat = 0;
    double lng = 0;
    float zoom = 0;
    double img = 0;

    locationCount = arg1.getCount();
    arg1.moveToFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < locationCount; i++) {
        lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));
        lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));
        zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));
        img = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMG));
        LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        drawMarker(location);
        arg1.moveToNext();
    }

    if (locationCount > 0) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lng)));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(img));
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
    }
```

But then receives the following error:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 0.0: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I do not want to save the image as a `blob` as it is bad practice hence why I am saving the file path to the DB

If someone can please assist in guiding me to retrieve the file from the DB and display in my `ImageView`

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `I am saving the image taken by the camera to my SQLite database by using this code:` Sorry but i see you saving nothing. And the table FIELD_IMG cannot hold an image file but only text. So probably only a file path. If so then give that field a better non confusing name. Please elaborate and edit your post to solve this confusion.

Comment: Hi, its saving the image file path to that FIELD_IMG in the following format `/storage/emulated/0/MapImages/MapImages/JPEG_20211105_091000_.jpg`  Si i can see the file being saved.  I just can't retrieve the file to display in the `ImageView`.  And the FIELD_IMG is as a `text` not a blob

Comment: `Please edit your post to solve this confusion` We wait until you did.

Comment: Sorry that it is confusing to you but the question is quite clear.

1. Save image taken by Camera to SQLite Database
2. Image file path (not blob) is saved to table in this format `/storage/emulated/0/MapImages/MapImages/JPEG_20211105_091000_.jpg`
3. Having trouble retrieving the image file from the table to display in the `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```java
img = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMG));
```

with:

```java
img = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMG));
```

This will also require you to declare `img` as a `String`.

A filesystem path is a string, not a floating-point number.

Comment: Hi @Commonsware,  Thanks for your assistance.  The issue I am facing now is this:  `Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Images/MyImage_20211105_130843.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`  The permissions are correct, but when I try and browse to that location on my phone (or look in the gallery app) I don't see the file (photo)?

Comment: @Keith: `Uri.forFile()` will not work by default on Android 7.0 and higher. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: So basically I need to re-write my entire code? :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out and what to do to use as mentioned above.  but am getting this error now.  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getCanonicalPath()' on a null object reference`